# Sound cuts out, PC says it's still playing. Randomly works if I unplug and replug usb mouse.

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, audio, mouse

This is just weird and I cannot find any similar issue online.

Normally while playing a game, the laptop's sound cuts out completely. Unplugging the mouse and replugging it in sometimes works.

The laptop's sound mixer shows that music is playing. But there is no actual sound.

Comment: Does the sound cut out only during games? That would be strange. Mouse affecting audio sounds like some sort of loose contact or short inside.